# Grails - Can't call service from Controller --> always get "Cannot invoke method on null object error"

Tags: java, grails, groovy, controller, service

i have a grails application and i'm following the tutorial here:
http://www.grails.org/Services

i have some code like

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean

class SubmitRequestService implements InitializingBean{
    def GrailsApplication1
    def setting

    void afterPropertiesSet(){
        this.setting = GrailsApplication1.config.setting
    }

    def void sendHistoricalContract(HistoricalContract hc_instance){
        //... blah blah whatever code      
    }
}

class SubmitRequestController {    
    def submitRequestService
    static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "POST", delete: "POST"]

    def index = {
        // .... blah blah whatever code
        submitRequestService.sendHistoricalContract(historicalContractInstance)
    }    
}
```

No whatever i do, i can't seem to get the service to be injected into the controller. Whenever I get to the line where i call the service i get the error:

> ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - Cannot invoke method sendHistoricalContract() on null object

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Burt's answer is helpful (+1 to Burt) but in case others are following the tutorial here:
http://www.grails.org/Services
and experiencing the same issue i had, i want to make it explicit:

> Services go in their own files under
>   the Services directory, you do not
>   combine them with controllers, even
>   though it looks that way in the code
>   examples

See Burt's comment above on additional resources to Services and the Spring Framework.

Comment: Original link seems to be dead. Here's the updated link to 2.x user guide chapter concerning "Services": http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Services/Usage.html

Answer (score 6):

GrailsApplication1 looks weird - what's that coming from? If you want to access the GrailsApplication instance to get to the config, use a dependency injection for the `grailsApplication` Spring bean:

```
class SubmitRequestService implements InitializingBean {

   private setting

   def grailsApplication

   void afterPropertiesSet() {
       setting = grailsApplication.config.setting
   }

   void sendHistoricalContract(HistoricalContract hc_instance) {
      //... blah blah whatever code      
   }
}
```

My guess is that GrailsApplication1 is causing a problem with the service that's keeping it from being injected into the controller, but I would think that it'd blow up with an exception at startup. Try running `grails clean` to force a full recompile.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I'm really new to grails and just following the tutorials. As i turns out, I hadn't declared the SubmitRequestService inside the Services folder (I just add the class declaration in the same file as the controller). After moving the service declaration into it's own file in the appropriate folder, it compiles and runs now. Is there some documentation or tutorials you can point me at with respect to services and creating a service that implements InitializingBean? thanks

Comment: Just implement `InitializingBean`, `afterPropertiesSet()` will get called. Or what are you asking about?

Comment: @w InitializingBean is a Spring interface, so there are lots of Spring resources (their user manual, many books) that you can reference. One issue with Grails is that the MetaClass methods are wired up after the Spring ApplicationContext works is done, there are timing issues there. One example is that the dynamically added 'log' field isn't available in afterPropertiesSet. There aren't many issues like this, so the standard Spring docs will be useful.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this before.

I change it to `grailsApplication1` and it worked.

Then you call:

```
this.setting = grailsApplication1.config.setting
```

**Notice the case of the service**