# Cannot invoke method pullLogs() on null object when calling service in controller

Tags: grails, service

I have search around stack overflow and have found some similar instances of my problem but there fixes done seem to work for mine. (example of simular one:[Grails - Can't call service from Controller --> always get "Cannot invoke method on null object error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559270/grails-cant-call-service-from-controller-always-get-cannot-invoke-method))

My service can be summed up like this

```
class AuditService {


  AuditService auditService

  def sql
  def dataSource
  static transactional = true


  def pullLogs(String username, String id) { 
    if(username != null && id != null) {

        sql = new Sql(dataSource)
        println "Data source is: " + dataSource.toString()
        def schema = dataSource.properties.defaultSchema

        sql.query('select USERID, AUDIT_DETAILS from DEV.AUDIT_LOG T WHERE XMLEXISTS(\'\$s/*/user[id=\"' + id + '\" or username=\"'+username+'\"]\' passing T.AUDIT_DETAILS as \"s\") ORDER BY AUDIT_EVENT', []) { ResultSet rs ->
            while (rs.next()) { 
                def auditDetails = new XmlSlurper().parseText(rs.getString('AUDIT_EVENT_DETAILS'))
                println auditDetails
            }
        }
        sql.close()
    }
}
```

}

The way im trying to call it is likes this

```
UserController {

  def auditService


  show(Long id){

    def UserInstance = User.get(id)

    //Also tried def auditResults = auditServices.pullLogs(UserInstance.username, UserInstance.id)
    def auditResults = auditServices(UserInstance.username, UserInstance.id)
    System.out.println(" "+ auditResults)
    [UserInstance: UserInstance,params:params]
  }
}
```

The error I get is

```
Class:
java.lang.NullPointerException
Message:
 Cannot invoke method pullLogs() on null object
```

Im pretty stumped. (Query was given to me)

Any Ideas/Opnions/Help is greatly appriciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In UserController you have

```
def auditService
```

But then

```
def auditResults = auditServices(UserInstance.username, UserInstance.id)
```

which should be

```
def auditResults = auditService.pullLogs(UserInstance.username, UserInstance.id)
```

As for the "FactoryBean not initialized" error, for that you can simply remove the

```
AuditService auditService
```

from inside `AuditService` - it isn't necessary as you can just use `this` if you need a reference to AuditService from within its own code.

Comment: Still no luck =(. Sorry for my jumbled code. Been tinkering with it for awhile. I need to just stop. revise. Then tinker some more.

Comment: @CoffeePeddlerIntern this may be a silly question, but AuditService.groovy is under `grails-app/services`, and UserController.groovy under `grails-app/controllers`, right?

Comment: Yes. But I have resolved my issue. I re-checked out the project and now it just magically works. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @CoffeePeddlerIntern yes, when strange things happen with grails I often find some level of cleaning (`grails clean`, or delete `target`, or delete `~/.grails`) followed by a rebuild will magically fix it :-)

Comment: @IanRoberts Your comment helped me resolve my issue. I had the service method running fine on development but fail on production with the same error message as the OP. a build prod clean followed by build war solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

The name of your service is `LogService` or `AuditService`? If it's `AuditService` your attribute name in the controller have an `s` that shouldn't.

```
class UserController {
  def auditService //Name should be the same of the service, not in plural
  ...
}
```

Comment: I changed up my source to resemble. I switched/renamed  some of the names. Now when I do that I get the error
    Error creating bean with name 'auditService': org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBeanNotInitializedException: FactoryBean is not fully initialized yet

Comment: I get to the point of trying everything I forget what was original or what worked last sometimes =S.